# How to update the state of store when we add new data by api

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I am new in React-native and Redux, I am trying to do CRUD operation. How to update the state of store when we add data by api. I am calling `Get Business Api` in may action. and I store it into Store.

business action:

```
export const getBusinessByAliases = (aliases) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(getBusinessByAliasesData(aliases))
    //API CALL
      getBusiness(aliases)
          .then(response=>{
        //HERE I GET WHOLE BUSINESS DATA
              dispatch(getBusinessByAliasesSuccess(response.data.business))
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log("err",err)
              dispatch(getBusinessByAliasesFailure(err))
          })
  }
}
```

business data  is:

```
 business:[
        "id": "17bfdde3-bc04-4a9c-87e7-7530ded1b929",
            "inserted_at": "2019-07-10T09:47:41",
            "name": "Business2",
     "employees": [
                {
                    "nickname": "xyz",
                    "settings": null,
                    "user": {
                        "email": null,
                        "first_name": null,
                        "id": "582f5d07-146e-4a81-a6c0-7dd5208b43b2",
                        "image_id": null,
                        "inserted_at": "2019-07-02T13:41:06",
                        "last_name": null,
                        "phone": "+911234567890"
                    }
                }
            ],
"services": [
                {
                    "id": "34bd8c80-41e1-459a-bc09-d88a6894bd42",
                    "name": "Gsgsha",
                    "settings": {
                        "color": "#039BE5",
                        "duration": 4,
                        "price": 6
                    }
                }
            ],
]
```

Now i am adding customer by calling create employee api in another action
employee action :

```
export const createNewEmployee = (businessName,data) => {
  //console.log("whole data", data)
  return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(createEmployee(businessName,data))
    // API CALL
      createEmployees(businessName,data)
          .then(response=>{
            //IN RESPONSE I GET SUCCESS MESSAGE WITH TRANSACTION ID
              dispatch(createEmployeeSuccess(response.data.transaction_id))
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log("errEmp",err)
              dispatch(createEmployeeFailure(err))
            })
  }
}
```

Now, How do I update by the business state which contains all data with my new added employee entry?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is that your endpoint should response the new business object with all employes or only the new list of employes.

Keep in mind that your server can be modified by a lot of app clients, if you need to keep the information updated, you need to implement a Firebase protocol to update your store every time.